# How to fetch last inserted record from MySQL database in flutter

Tags: mysql, flutter

**flutter MySQL fetch last saved data from MySQL database**

how to fetch the saved data from the database, not to retrieve all the records but the data which saved last need to retrieve and show n next screen in flutter

Comment: You don't have access directly to the database this part is a backend job

Comment: @Joseph how to do that,am using mysql database and using php to save the data to database .whenever i click the save button , the data get saved in my database and now i dont know how to fetch that data and show on another screen

Comment: So, this is a PHP and MySQL problem please update your question or remove it and create new one

Comment: Hi @Anugrahc.p! What's the structure of your mysql table? What are the columns in it?

Answer (score 0):

use this in your query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```